# A question in theory of free groups in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

I am self studying abstract algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I have a question in it in the chapter of free groups.

I have a question on page 65 of the book. I am adding it's image.

[image]

> Question is in line 6 of sketch of proof.

> Question : What is the reasoning behind author reducing $ |x| |x^{-1}| = 1_{F} $ .

Kindly tell.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: $x$ is one of the generators, not an arbitrary term.

Comment: By $|x||x^{-1}|$, the author means the composite of the two functions $|x|$ and $|x^{-1}|$. You can use the given definition of those two functions to show that the composite is the identity.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I just realized that. In fact, my original comment still works!

Comment: @Rob Arthan the problem is that I don't understand how defination implies that the product is identity. So, can you tell in more detail?

Comment: What is $|x||x^{-1}|(x_1^{\delta_1}\ldots x_n^{\delta_n})$? The given definition tells you how to calculate this (there are two cases depending on whether or not $x_1^{\delta_1} = x^{-1}$).

Comment: @Rob Arthan can you show your calculations if you have some time to spare?  I am still having trouble.

Comment: I've spelled out the details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show that $|x|(|x^{-1}|(w)) = w$ for every reduced word $w$.

If $w = 1$, I leave it for you to show that $|x|(|x^{-1}|(w)) = w$ (it should be easy if you understand what follows).
Otherwise, we can write $w = x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}$. According to the definition of $|x^{-1}|$, there are two cases:

Case 1) $x^{-1} \neq x_1^{-\delta_1}$: by the definition:
$$
|x^{-1}|(x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}) = x^{-1}x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}
$$
But then $|x|(x^{-1}x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n})$ falls under the second case in the definition so we have:
$$
|x|(x^{-1}x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}) = x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}
$$

Case 2): $x^{-1} = x_1^{-\delta_1}$, so that $x_1 = x$ and $\delta_1 = 1$: by the definition:
$$
|x^{-1}|(x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}) = x_2^{\delta_2}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}
$$
Note that because $x_1^{\delta_1}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}$ is reduced, either $x_2 \neq x_1$ or $\delta_2 = 1$. Hence $x \neq x_2^{-\delta_2}$ and  ${|x|}(x_2^{\delta_2}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n})$ falls under the first case of the definition so we have:
$$
|x|(x_2^{\delta_2}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}) = xx_2^{\delta_2}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}  = x_1^{\delta_1}x_2^{\delta_2}\cdots x_n^{\delta_n}
$$

So in both cases $|x|(|x^{-1}|(w)) = w$ and we are done.